# Error NU1002 when installng EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact to ASP.NET 5 project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, sql-server-ce

While installing "EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact" through NuGet to ASP.NET 5 project, got error:

> Error NU1002 The dependency EntityFramework 6.1.3 in project does not
>   support framework DNXCore,Version=v5.0

Other EntityFramework packages are of correct versions:

> ```
> "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
> "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
> ```

In Solution Explorer, error highlited in "DNX Core 5.0" branch of "References" tree.

Is there any way to solve this issue, or I should forget of using SQL Server Compact in ASP.NET 5 project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer provider only runs on the full .NET Framework, not on .NET Core

Comment: And?
I shall swith to ASP MVC 4(5), or there is some way to swith to full .NET in existing .NET 5 project?

Comment: Yes, you can use asp.net 5 with the full .net framework